# Getting a Play/SBT app to depend on a Maven POM

Tags: maven, playframework-2.0, sbt

My Play 2 application is a subproject of a larger Maven application. The Play 2 app has dependencies in its parent - it gets its data access from it. Therefore, I want the Build of the application to depend on the external Maven project.

Basically, I want to write this:

```
val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
   // settings
).dependsOn(externalPom(baseDirectory(_ / "../pom.xml")))
```

But of course this isn't valid syntax.

I've tried defining my `play.Project` like this:

```
val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
   externalPom(baseDirectory(_ / "../pom.xml"))
)
```

Which fails because (I think) the override causes Play to not load its own exception

I've tried defining a new `Project` like so:

```
lazy val data = Project("data", file(baseDirectory(_ / "..).settings(
   externalPom(baseDirectory(_ /         "../pom.xml"))
)
```

And depending on that, which does not work because there is no main class detected.

Any suggestions on how to do this? I'm new to SBT.

Comment: Sounds a bit odd - its there any chance to make that play 2 app independent?

Comment: We switched from Maven to SBT altogether. We never solved the problem in this question.

Comment: Perfectly reasonable!

Answer (score 0):

I am successfuly using play2-maven-plugin

http://nanoko-project.github.io/maven-play2-plugin/maven/release/

With this plugin you create maven module for play2 app as well and you define the dependencies (your data access layer) in maven pom. The plugin will ensure that play gets the dependencies (it copies the pom dependencies into the unmanaged dependencies in lib directory).

Using this plugin also allows to avoid many tedious rebuilds because you have everything in one project, so your IDE sees changes across all modules without a rebuild.

Also when you use the plugin, you don't have problems with updating snapshot maven dependencies from local maven repository (this sbt bug https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/321).

Answer (score 0):

I just did this with [play2-maven-plugin](https://code.google.com/p/play2-maven-plugin/) and [sbt-pom-reader](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-pom-reader).

This is how you need to configure your play2-maven project:

```
<my-maven-project>/
  pom.xml                  <- Your maven build
  build.sbt                <- the sbt Play 2 configuration
  project/
     build.properties      <- the sbt version specification
     build.scala           <- the sbt build definition
     plugins.sbt           <- the sbt plugin configuration

  ..                       <- Whatever files are normally in your maven project.
```

Each of the files should have the following contents.

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>play2</packaging>
    <name>My mavenified Play 2 application</name>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <play2.version>2.2.1</play2.version>
        <play2-scala.version>2.10</play2-scala.version>
        <play2.plugin.version>1.0.0-alpha5</play2.plugin.version>
        <scala.version>2.10.2</scala.version>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>typesafe</id>
            <name>Typesafe - releases</name>
            <url>http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>${scala.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.play</groupId>
            <artifactId>play_${play2-scala.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${play2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- only if using Java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.play</groupId>
            <artifactId>play-java_${play2-scala.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${play2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/app</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/conf</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>public/**</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <!--<outputDirectory>target/scala-${play2-scala.version}/classes</outputDirectory>-->
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.code.play2-maven-plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>play2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${play2.plugin.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.google.code.play2-maven-plugin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>play2-provider-play22</artifactId>
                        <version>${play2.plugin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <!-- only if using Java -->
                <configuration>
                    <mainLang>java</mainLang>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

build.sbt:

```
play.Project.playJavaSettings //or play.Project.playScalaSettings
```

project/build.properties:

```
sbt.version=0.13.0
```

project/build.scala:

```
object BuildFromMavenPomSettings extends com.typesafe.sbt.pom.PomBuild
```

project/plugins.sbt:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.1")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-pom-reader" % "1.0.1")
```

Comment: I have no practical way to verify whether this answer is correct, as I don't use Maven with SBT anymore. If anyone can verify this or the other answer, I'd be happy to mark a correct answer.